# How to display french charcaters in text view

Tags: android, encoding, character-encoding

For example the letter:  `À`.
Is displayed as a strange sign shape! I used the function `Html.fromHtml()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [unicode](http://unicode-table.com/en/#00C3)

```
TextView.setText("\U+00C1");
```

You can also hardcode the string if you have it pre defined -

```
<string name="FrenchChar">À</string>
```